# What is the relation between Linux kernel and GNU C library?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, glibc

We know that Linux kernel is written in C. But does it also call standard C functions like `malloc()` or extra functions like `mmap()` which are provided by GNU C library (glibc)? In that case, it's strange, because direct low-level interaction with hardware, e.g. memory management, is supposed to be almost always the task of a kernel. So, which is dependent on the other? Which is more fundamental/low-level?

Comment: The kernel should be more fundamental. If you search through the linux kernel source code, it defines `malloc` in several places...

Comment: @mnestorov, Are those parts written in assembly in the linux kernel source code?

Comment: I would assume some are. So the reason I'm saying this is because it doesn't make sense that the kernel will depend on glibc. There are many discussions which glibc version can be used with which kernel version, but that doesn't mean that the kernel depends on glibc. I just did a quick search in the linux source code and saw that malloc is defined in several places. How much assembly there is and what it is, I don't know.

Comment: @mnestorov, I haven't seen the source code of either, but it seems to me they are interdependent. For example, linux kernel may use the functions for string manipulation from glibc. On the other hand, glibc probably uses linux functions to implement its malloc().

Comment: *"I haven't seen the source code of either"* - so why are you here with question? Do some research, draw conclusions and ask what is unclear.  
Btw, take a look at [`/lib/string.c`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.161/source/lib/string.c) (where you can find `strlen()` and friends) and other similar files - read comments, [tag:git] history, etc.

Comment: @z0lupka, we don't have enough time to do all research ourselves. That's why we go to doctors, why we ask questions here, etc. Isn't that clear?

Comment: Nope, it's absolutely unclear, it smacks of disrespect and sounds like "I don't have a time, so go figure it out and dig into the code instead of me".
From the [WRITING THE PERFECT QUESTION](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/): *"You have searched for a solution to your problem before asking it, haven’t you? **Stack Overflow isn’t meant to replace basic search skills**"*. Have you heard about such utils like `git clone` and `grep`?

Comment: @apadana Why not? Downloading its source code is a 5 minute task. Finding what you're looking for in the source code, now that takes longer.

Comment: Nobody says you shouldn't ask. The thing is that you need to at least search for something yourself, and not use the "Ask Question" field as a request line in Google.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> We know that Linux kernel is written in C. But does it also call standard C functions like malloc()

No. However, the kernel defines similar functions like [`kmalloc`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-api/API-kmalloc.html). Note this is not part of a library; it's part of the kernel itself.

> or extra functions like mmap()

Not `mmap`, but there are [a lot](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-api/ch04s03.html) of memory management functions in the kernel.

> which are provided by GNU C library (glibc)?

Definitely not. The kernel does not use glibc ever.

> So, which is dependent on the other?

Some parts of glibc depends on the kernel. Other parts (like `strcpy`) have nothing to do with the kernel and don't depend on it. The kernel never depends on glibc. You can run programs on Linux that use a different libc (like "musl") or that don't use a libc at all.

Comment: Thanks. And glibc [is not listed](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.15/process/changes.html) as a requirement for compiling the Linux kernel.